# Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray()

Tags: php, function, magento, e-commerce

When I got to System >> COnfiguration >> Google API from my magento dashboard I get following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 421
```

In Form.php on line 421 there is following code.

```
} else {
                        $optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');
                    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that `$sourceModel` is an object, e.g. you've done something like: `$sourceModel = new Class;`

Comment: @PLB Thanks a lot. I solved it by going through all the module installed and updating them.

Comment: @Pekka I know I should have posted on Magento support forum, but it is very hard to get reply there. I love Stack Exchange because we get reply promptly here. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the above error. Please open the above path file.

```
if ($e->source_model) {
$sourceModel = Mage::getSingleton((string)$e->source_model);
if ($sourceModel instanceof Varien_Object) {
$sourceModel->setPath($path);
}
$field->setValues($sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect'));
}
```

Replace above code with below:

```
if ($e->source_model) {
$sourceModel = Mage::getSingleton((string)$e->source_model);
if ($sourceModel instanceof Varien_Object) {
$sourceModel->setPath($path);
}
if(is_object($sourceModel)){
$field->setValues($sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect'));
} else {
Mage::log($e->source_model);
}
}
```

Source: http://indianicorange.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-tooptionarray-on-a-non-object/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I went through the Magento log. The error was caused by Fooman GoogleAnalyticsPlus module. Upgrading it fixed the issue.