# Magento Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > System - Fatal Error

Tags: magento, configuration, php

I get this error when I try to access System > Configuration > Advanced > System

Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /home/server/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 421

I found this answer: [Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773148/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-tooptionarray)

However, the code that needs to be replaced according to that answer is different from the code in that file (Form.php):

```
         if ($method) {
                if ($fieldType == 'multiselect') {
                    $optionArray = $sourceModel->$method();
                } else {
                    $optionArray = array();
                    foreach ($sourceModel->$method() as $value => $label) {
                        $optionArray[] = array('label' => $label, 'value' => $value);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');
            }
            $field->setValues($optionArray);
        }
    }
}
return $this;
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you recently added a module or been working on installing your own module? Typically, the above error comes from having a fubar'd code in a dropdown array. Turn on all logging, put Magento into developer mode and you should get a message in the exception log telling you which array is busted.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in Form.php from line 398 to 425 you have almost the same code. The code from your answer isn't a fix, is just a way to help you determine your real problem, so you can use that code:

```
if(is_object($sourceModel)){
    $field->setValues($sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect'));
} else {
    Mage::log($e->source_model);
}
```

And then you would have to look into the Magento log file to see what happened.
Also you can try to log debug_print_backtrace();
Probably your problem comes from a badly written extension.

Comment: The real solution is to find out what module cause that error. Try to disable one at a time until you won't have that error. Also take a look on your log files for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should solve the error:-

1. **Disable Compilation** (`System -> Tools -> Compilation`)
2. **Refresh Cache** (`System -> Cache Management`)

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao for the info. Will follow the guidelines.