# Was not able to Access System > Configuration > Advance > System tab in magento admin?

Tags: php, magento

When i am trying to access the System > Configuration > Advanced > System tab in magento admin it is giving me the following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 526

#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(526): mageCoreErrorHandler(8,'Trying to get p...', '/app/code/c...', 526, Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_sortForm('1', 'text')
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(266): usort(Array, Array)
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(210): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(102): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

I tried verifying the source file, but there is no change in the source code. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Kimi

Comment: Do you have any local or community modules install?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the file magento/var/.htaccess, the directories magento/app/etc, magento/var, and all the directories under magento/media are writable by the web server.

or look this

[Magento Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > System - Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891826/magento-admin-system-configuration-advanced-system-fatal-error/10898159#10898159)

[Magento Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > System - Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891826/magento-admin-system-configuration-advanced-system-fatal-error/10898159#10898159)

Comment: Thanks for the response, i verified the Permissions of all the files and directories they are fine. Even when i tried to see the log file nothing is getting updated in the log file. I am not sure that the above error is same as my error.